# Drupal taxonomy-term text-body dependency

Tags: taxonomy-terms

i'm using drupal for a website where i post from time to time different events. For this, i made a taxonomy type with four vocabularies, each stands for another event type.

**Now my question:**
I know that i can put a default text in the body of events which appears when a new event were created. But i want that this text depends on the taxonomy term which is chosen for this event.

I'm guessing that i have to write an php script with an if ... then ... condition. But where i have to write this code and how can i address the taxonomy terms and the body of new events?

I'm a beginner, so please answer a bit more detailed. If i know at the end how to do this, maybe it will help me with a lot of other stuff. Greetings

Comment: When you say "when a new event were created" do you mean when a new event has been added, or just when someone is on the "new event" form. 

Because if they were just on the new event form, they haven't chosen an event type, so how could the default text be added to the body of the event?

But if it's after the node got added, then shouldn't you be assuming the user had already entered some content into the event body?

Comment: Hey Terry, thank you for the answer. I mean  when someone is on the event form and want to create a new event. The text body and the drop down menu of the taxonomy term are both on the event form. Sure when he opens the form, the textbody is still empty. But when he choose a taxonomy term in a drop down menu, for example 'special event' the text of the body should change immediately in an other default text. Is this possible?